# Select Result only if unique (sort of)

Tags: mysql, sql, logic

I am building a simple sql query, though I cant get my head around this one.
This is the layout for the table:

[image]

[image]

Challange: I would like to grap all from this table, only if there is an entry (by id_order) which does not have a threshold of 20 (which in this case, only ID 18 should be shown dynamically).

I was thinking going with:

```
SELECT * FROM `cancelorders_history` WHERE threshold != 20 GROUP BY `id_order`
```

Though this throws following error (and Im not sure that the query is matching the logic Im looking for, like explained above):

```
Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'exampletable.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

I cant use:

```
SELECT * FROM `cancelorders_history` WHERE threshold != 20
```

Because gives me both ID of 13,18,19.

What would be the preferred method to go around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I think you can use `not exists`:

```
select coh.*
from cancelorders_history coh
where not exists (select 1
                  from cancelorders_history coh2
                  where coh2.id_order = coh.id_order and coh2.threshold >= 20
                 );
```

Or, use a window function:

```
select coh.*
from (select coh.*,
             max(threshold) over (partition by id_order) as max_threshold
      from cancelorders_history coh
     ) coh
where max_threshold < 20;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an error on the `GROUP BY` because you have to have a group for every column you `SELECT`. Code should be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM cancelorders_history WHERE threshold != 20 GROUP BY threshold, notification_sent, id_order, id;
```

Yet, your query does not meet the requirements to only get one result. Doesn't look like want to use `GROUP BY`. Perhaps `ORDER BY`, but you'll have to explain the logic you really want to use.